# Background color not applied when grid overflows css

Tags: css, grid

```css
.wrap, .grid, .item {
  height: 100px;
}

.wrap {
  width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: pink;
  overflow: auto;
}

.grid {
  background-color: green;
  display: grid;
  column-gap: 80px;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px;
}

.item {
  background-color: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The grid will be more than 500px because of the grid's column template values. However, the grid has the same width only up to 500px. So it looks pink.

How can I make the grid's width change dynamically?

Comment: use inline-grid instead of grid

Answer (score 0):

It was very simple.

```css
.grid {
  width: min-content;
}
```